# Can't start running a local Grails app

Tags: grails

I'm in the repository where the cloned Grails app is located in local. I run this command to run and it says:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Task 'bootRun' not found in root project 'vagnkort'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug                                                                                                                      option to get more log output.
```

When I write ls, my listing is:

```
README.md       build           grails-app      grailsw.bat     web-app
application.properties  docs            grailsw         src     wrapper
```

Comment: did you tried running application using "grails run-app" command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the solution was that I had to run the relevant version of grails. In my case, I had to install the version 2.5.0 (of course this depends on the application build):

```
gvm install grails 2.5.0
```

Then switch to that version:

```
gvm use grails 2.5.0
```

You might have to switch to that version (that the application is built with) every each time you start the Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Try to run "grails clean" to clean up everything and then "grails run-app"